# Logical OR operator is not working in IF condition, solidity 0.5.0

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I wanted to ask if is it available to use OR operator in IF conditions, because its giving me awkward results, like this:

```js
contract test {
  if(player1Points > Player2Points || player1Points >= 50){
      result = 1;
  }
}
```

any help ??

Comment: "giving me awkward results" - what awkward results??? And why have you posted a code that doesn't even compile???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use it.

From the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html?highlight=%22logical%20disjunction%22#value-types):

> The operators `||` and `&&` apply the common short-circuiting rules. This
>   means that in the expression `f(x) || g(y)`, if `f(x)` evaluates to `true`,
>   `g(y)` will not be evaluated even if it may have side-effects.

Try with this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test {

    function comparePoints (uint player1Points, uint player2Points) public pure returns (uint) {
        uint result;

        if(player1Points > player2Points || player1Points >= 50){
            result = 1;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Maybe the following sections will be useful to start writing smart contracts.

- [Structure of a Contract](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure-of-a-contract.html#structure-of-a-contract)
- [Contracts](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#contracts)